# What is the sense the "either" as an object in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, objects

This is the first time I see the **either** at the end of a sentence to be an object.

> I don’t think women and men are different, and I don’t even think age groups are either.

I guess the **either** means **different** here, but is the structure of this sentence right and how to understand the **either**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It marks the second clause to mark it as being similar in structure or meaning to the first.  It is used with negative statements

> I don't like jam. I don't like peanut butter either.

Its use here is rather redundant. It doesn't add much to the meaning.  With positive sentences you would use "too"   "I like jam. I like peanut butter too." Words like "also" and "as well" have similar meanings

In your example the word "different" would be repeated. The speaker has chosen to omit this word, the listener is supposed to understand

> ... I don’t even think age groups are either

as

> ...I don’t even think age groups are different, either.

The word "either" doesn't mean "different".  But it can help the listener work out that a word has been omitted, since it links the two parts.

> Cars aren't fun, and bikes aren't either.

In that example, the word "fun" has been omitted.  ("and bikes aren't fun, either")

Comment: In your example, the **either** is not a subject, but in my example, it is. Is there a difference between them?

Comment: It's not a subject. It's probably best thought of as an adverb.  It has the same function in both examples.  In your example the word "different" has been deleted, I shall clarify.

Comment: Do you want to express that the original sentence should be: **I don’t even think age groups are either different.**? Just the **different** has been deleted? Is the original sentence right?

Comment: " I don’t even think age groups are different, either"  The adverb doesn't modify "different",  it goes at the end.

Comment: Is this sentence grammarly right: **I don’t think women and men are different, and I don’t even think age groups are either.**?